# Modelbuilder Iteration with Intersect Tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iteration

I am trying to create a model that will select each feature within a feature class, then perform an intersect between that selection and another layer.  The model setup seems rather straightforward, but I run into a problem with the output file name.  I want the file name to be the same as the input for the selected layer (the one on which I am performing the iteration), so I originally tried %NAME%; however, this function is supposed to cause it to be named after the input file and in this case, there are two inputs since I performing an intersect.

Here is the model I have drafted below for clarity.  I want to select each feature in Main_Lanes separately and intersect it with the Seg1_WZ layer to get an ouput point intersect named after the Main_Lanes selected feature.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, you have two inputs:

**Main_Lanes

Seg1_WZ**

Which when you want to name other files based on those names, you would reference them as:

**%Main_Lanes%

%Seg1_WZ%**

However, you want your output to have the same name as your Main_Lanes input, but the issue is you're appending **_File** to your output parameter name, when you should be naming it like so:

**%Main_Lanes%_File**

So what you'll end up with are features named:

Input1_File
Input2_File
Input3_File
etc, etc...

Let me know if that makes sense...

Comment: This may have answered my question, but I should have clarified about the _File.  I am iterating the feature class based on the field "File".  The result that I would like would be to have a final points file (from the intersect) with the same name as is in the File field for each feature.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Angela i wonder if you need to use a different type of iterator... have you tried the "Field" iterator?

Comment: The field that I want the file to be named after is a text field, so I don't think this will work.

Comment: @Angela you might need to use a field iterator and pull from a submodel that uses a feature class iterator...